HTMLMediaElement.currentTime - Reduced time precision
How to enable privacy.resistFingerprinting in Firefox?

What does the title have to do with the question?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime#reduced_time_precision

Well to enable it you go into your Firefox about:config an set the property. You cannot change the setting in a client browser from your own web-delivered content.
